# How to get value from multiple id's in a search form to be used in a axios call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a working version using jquery, but am running into many problems doing it in react.

Here is my jquery code..

```
    var filter1 = $("#IDXT001").val();
    var filter2 = $("#IDXT002").val();
    var filter3 = $("#IDXT003").val();

    var queryURL = "http://api/ixmasterdocument?filter=idxt001|" + filter1 + "&filter=idxt002|" + filter2 + "&filter=idxt003|" + filter3;

$.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    }).then(data => {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.map(function(contracts) {
          return contracts.Fields.map(function(docs) {
            return "<p>" + docs.DisplayName + ": " + docs.DataValue + "</p>";
          }).join("<br/>");
```

Trying to create the same in react..

```
import axios from "axios"; 

const filter1 = document.getElementById("IDXT001").val();
const filter2 = document.getElementById("IDXT002").val();
const filter3 = document.getElementById("IDXT003").val();

const BASEURL = "http://api/ixmasterdocumentfilter=idxt001|" + filter1 + "&filter=idxt002|" + filter2 + "&filter=idxt003|" + filter3

export default {
 search: function(query) {
   return axios.get(BASEURL + query);
 }
 };
state = {
  labels: [],
  results: [],
  contracts: [],
  search: "",

};

loadContracts = (query) => {
  API.search(query)
  .then(res => {
    const contracts = res.data;
    this.setState({ contracts })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
handleInputChange = event => {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
};

handleFormSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.loadContracts(this.state.search);
};
```

Here is where I am rendering..

```
           <Input  
            onChange={props.handleInputChange}
            value={props.search}
            type="text" 
            className={"form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"} 
            id={label.DataField}
           />
```

The errors that I get are "val() is null".
And when I use ref instead of id, I get "Function components cannot have refs"

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `state` to handle the `filters values`. so you have to add a method called `componentDidMount`,  in this component you can initialize the values of your elements. I think that your problem is that you are getting the values after the component is ready.

First of all you have to add to the initial state two properties :

```
state = {
  labels: [],
  results: [],
  contracts: [],
  search: "",
  filters: [],
  isReady: false,
};
```

Then you have to initialize this values , so when you make your ajax call you are sure that you have the values in the state.

Then you make the calls in componentDidMount.

```
initializeFilters = () => {

  const filter1 = document.getElementById("IDXT001").val();
  const filter2 = document.getElementById("IDXT002").val();
  const filter3 = document.getElementById("IDXT003").val();

  this.setState({ 
     filters: [filter1, filter2, filter3], 
     isReady: true
   });
}

componentDidMount(){
  initializeFilters();
}
```

So in your ajax you may have something like this:

```
    var queryURL = "http://api/ixmasterdocument?filter=idxt001|" + this.state.filter[0] + "&filter=idxt002|" + this.state.filter[1] + "&filter=idxt003|" + this.state.filters[2];

$.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    }).then(data => {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.map(function(contracts) {
          return contracts.Fields.map(function(docs) {
            return "<p>" + docs.DisplayName + ": " + docs.DataValue + "</p>";
          }).join("<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `document.getElementById` or `refs` for accessing form values. You should store all your values in state. This way, you'll be able to access them via `this.state`.

If you need to initialize any values via an Ajax request. You should do so in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle.

Take a look at how they write forms in React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Also, I don't see a function or a class being declared and I don't see you importing React at all in the code snippets you've provided. That should definitely be there.